# How to change the value of a specific field in firebase using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change the value of "check" for particular values of "attendance"

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').doc().set({
            'doc':FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').doc(),
            'attendance':title,
            'check':true
          });
```

[image: Here's the firebase database]

What code should I use if I want to change the value of the field of that particular documents.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace set to update Like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').doc().update({
     
            'check':true
          });
```

Comment: I want to chang check value for particular values of attendance, not for all.

Comment: ok, so you need to add (where ) after collection('students'), to can filter it , and update specific document

Answer (score 0):

When you call `doc()` without parameters it generates a reference to a **new** document.

If you want to update an existing document, you'll need to pass the ID of tht document to the `doc(...)` call.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').doc('rYvghLkro3pYcclwpCPI').update({
  'attendance': 'new title',
});
```

If you don't know the ID of the document you want to update, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to look that up based on some value(s) in the document that you *do* know.